# RocketSocket error -- No known instance method for base64EncodedData

Tags: objective-c, socketrocket

I'm attempting to use the `RocketSocket` library on a OS 10.7 but Xcode keeps complaining that the property `base64Encoding` not found in `NSData` and `NSMutable` regarding these lines in `SRWebSocket.m`:

```
return [[NSData dataWithBytes:md length:CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH] base64Encoding];
```

---

```
_secKey = keyBytes.base64Encoding;
```

After some googling, I found that `base64Encoding` is deprecated. I'm a relative noob to ObjC (and Mac in general). Anyone have any idea how to fix this problem?

Comment: Could you please post more of the code so we can get some context, and the whole of the error rather than a precis. On the face of it, the two lines you've included should work so it's likely to be a problem elsewhere.

Comment: The error message in the question title mentions a different method than what is shown in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
_secKey = keyBytes.base64Encoding
```

by

```
_secKey = [keyBytes base64EncodedStringWithOptions:NSDataBase64Encoding64CharacterLineLength];
```